# visual studio 2017 xamarin doesn't show any signing identities in properties of ios project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Earlier everything was ok. now on ios project properties
Signing identity has two items: Developer(Automatic), Distribution(Automatic)
and Provisioning profile has Automatic.

When I open a project where provisioning profile is set, it shows it like "Unknown(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" and builds fine. but when I chose Automatic "Unknown(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" disappears and I'm unable chose it again.

Mac agent is connected fine (because it builds fine in above case)

Everything regarding VC,Xamarin on the Mac and PC is updated to the last update.

Comment: Have you tried to check  if `Provisioning profile`  can be set correctly in Xcode ?

Comment: Got this exact same thing. Nothing seems to help.